# iOS APNS not recv'd on device for dev and prod even tho http2 returns code 200

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, jwt, http2

Ive recently changed the iOS APNS to use http2 with JWT rather than
certificates.  Initially it worked and all was well.  At some point I
broke it because I was not receiving development APN's, but production
was working.  After revoking both APN dev/prod certificates and making new
ones and getting a new APN token for push (during the course of trying to fix my first issue), my alerts are now broken for both (dev & production) even though the HTTP feedback code is 200.

I then tried to fix both issues with no luck.  Im sure the code that I had
working is still working, but it seems like apple is having some issue
that they aren't showing up on my device(s) at all.

```
Things Ive done/checked:
1. Re-created both dev and production push certificates
2. both dev and prod mobile provision profiles have been re-done/downloaded and installed.
3. Apple ID's show both Dev and Prod push is 'enabled'
4. in Xcode->Capabilities Push Notifications are turned on
5. deleted the app and re-installed for both dev and prod devices
6. made sure the APN device token (in My Application) is being updated to the server
7. Made sure Im sending to the right Dev/Prod push servers
```

Unless there's some order of doing things I didn't get right between
the developer portal and installing in Xcode, Im unsure where to go 
from here.  Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

[SOLVED]
I found that the APN payload string had a problem.  It would be helpful
if apple could give some feedback code for that however the fact that
it returns code 200 may be indication enough that something is wrong with
the payload string.

Answer (score 2):

Using single quotes instead of double quotes in the JSON payload will cause this:

```
        string payload = "{ 'aps' : { 'alert' : 'Hello' } }";  // wrong

        string payload = "{ \"aps\" : { \"alert\" : \"Hello\" } }";  // right
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sending a test push notification using command line. If that works then there is some issue in your server settings. If not then the issue is with your SSL certificate